# vb 2013 return a bool from function

Tags: vb.net

```
Function checkIsAuthorized(ByVal users As String) As Boolean
    Dim UserJobCode As String = dcChris.getJobCode(users)
    Dim values As String = My.Settings.canResendJobcode
    Dim usersCode As String() = values.Split(",")

    Return usersCode.Contains(UserJobCode)


    'If usersCode.Contains(UserJobCode) Then
    '    canResend = True
    '    Return True
    'End If
    'canResend = False
    'Return False
End Function
```

The commented portion of the function works, I was just trying to make the code more efficient with the return statement.  But it does not return a bool because the global is still reading false.  Doing it the old way worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you also want to set `canResend`, you need two statements `canResend = usersCode.Contains(UserJobCode)` followed by `Return canResend`.

Answer (score 0):

Dim canResend As Boolean

Function checkIsAuthorized(ByVal users As String) As Boolean
        Dim UserJobCode As String = dcChris.getJobCode(users)
        Dim values As String = My.Settings.canResendJobcode
        Dim usersCode As String() = values.Split(",")
        Return usersCode.Contains(UserJobCode)

```
End Function
```

This is what I settled on.  It works great for my needs.  Thanks everyone.